# Why Dusk isn't running JavaScript in Homestead env?

Tags: laravel, selenium-chromedriver, laravel-dusk

I'm starting to test my porjects with Laravel's Dusk, I use Homestead as my development environment, I istalled everything that is required to run Dusk, even Google Chrome. Everything is running smoothly, besides anything that requires JavaScript to run.

```php
public function testExample()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/login')
                    ->type('username', 'admin')
                    ->type('password', 'password')
                    ->press('Login')
                    ->assertPathIs('/home')
                    ->visit('/path/test')
                    ->assertPathIs('/path/test')
                    ->select('field1', '1')
                    ->assertSelected('field1', '1')
                    ->select('field2', '1')
                    ->assertSelected('field2', '1')
                    ->select('field3', '1')
                    ->script('$(".component").show(); $(".field4").show();'); //Forcing script to show a component
            $browser->assertSee('Text:') 
                    ->select('field4', '1')
                    ->assertSelected('field4', '1')
                    ->type('field5', 'Test Dusk')
                    ->type('field6', 'Dusk')
                    ->type('field7', 'www.laravel.com')
                    ->select('field8', '2')
                    ->click('#btn-save')
                    ->waitFor('.modaldialog')
                    ->assertSee('Save');

        });
    }
```

The script that I forced is dependent on field1, when selected it must execute a JS to show a new component and one new selectbox. The only way I can run JS is with the script function. The end of the test is a JavaScript dialog to confirm the form and send a post request. I look everywhere for answers, but found nothing. Any ideas what can I do?

Comment: Do this script runs in the console. Try putting a $browser->tinker(); just before the script command and manually try to execute some other script.

Comment: I tried to execute until the first js is used, this is what I got `PHPUnit/Framework/ExpectationFailedException with message 'Did not see expected text [Tipo de Participantes:] within element [body].
Failed asserting that false is true.'
 ` 
The js don't work unless I use the script function :|